# Simple way to select a few rows of data from table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am transitioning from SQL Server to BigQuery and noticed that the TOP function in BigQuery is only allowed to aggregate in queries. Therefore the below code would not work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE
```

This is a habit I've had when trying to learn new tables and get more information on the data. Is there another alternative to selecting a few rows from the table? The following select all query works, but is incredibly inefficient and takes a long time to run for large tables:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Comment: [`LIMIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_and_offset_clause)

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery, you can use `LIMIT` as in:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
LIMIT 5;
```

But I caution you to be *very* careful with this.  BigQuery charges for the number of *columns* accessed in a table, not the number of rows.  So, in a large table, such a query can be quite expensive.

You can also go into the BigQuery GUI, navigate to the table, and click on "Preview".  The preview functionality is free.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon Linoff mentioned, using LIMIT statement in BigQuery may be very expensive when used with big tables. To make exploratory queries more cost effective BigQuery now supports  [TABLESAMPLE operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#tablesample_operator), see also [Using table sampling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling#using_table_sampling).
Sampling returns a variety of records while avoiding the costs associated with scanning and processing an entire table.

Query example:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (2 PERCENT)
```

Comment: makes sense, but cant be used with views.  just fyi.  "TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM can only be applied directly to base tables."

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying e.g. table views or `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM` is not working for other reasons, what you can do is to use e.g.  `[...] WHERE RAND() < 0.05` for getting 5% of the results randomly selected. Make sure to put it at the end of your query in the WHERE statement.

This works also with table views and if you are not the owner of a table. :)